# (GA4) cannot find the custom param value of event and user properties in exploration report

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I have send data to GA by a simple POST method

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=<measurement_id>&api_secret=<api_secret>

payload: 
{
    "client_id": "123",
    "user_properties": {
        "testing_database_id": {
            "value": "database id 1"
        },
        "testing_user_id": {
            "value": "user 1"
        }
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "user_action_logs",
            "params": {
                "first_field_name": "102",
                "action_name": "123",
                "database_id": "database_id 123"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

I can see the event record with the value I send in real time window, but not the user properties.
Also only show the (not set) value in exploration report

[image]

How can I find the value of event and user properties in exploration report?
Thanks.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: I've send data to GA at 3rd - 4th July, first check the exploration report at July 4. And it still shows with value (not set) at 7th July.

Comment: Do you have more pages of events your not looking at the event name user_action_logs

Comment: Thanks for help. I found the data in exploration report now. It just take more time, around 5 days.